# angular controller as watch variable in parent controller

Tags: angularjs, parent, watch, controlleras

how do i watch a variable, that is bind to a parent controller?

```
function config($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'home.html',
            controller: 'HomeController',
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        })

        .state('home.child', {
            url: '/child',
            templateUrl: 'child.html',
            controller: 'ChildController',
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        });
}

function HomeController($scope) {
    this.title = 'Some Title';
}

function ChildController($scope) {
    var vm = this;
    $scope.$watch('vm.title', function(current, original) {
        $log.info('title was %s', original);
        $log.info('title is now %s', current);
    });

}
```

The watch-Function doesn't recognize changes on the parent title..

thanks! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just access the `$parent` scope when referencing objects belonging to the parent. Also get used to a cleaner and more standardized way of structuring your controller JS.

HTML

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <body>
    <div ng-controller="HomeController">
      <input type="text" ng-model="title">
      <div ng-controller="ChildController"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("HomeController", ['$scope', '$log', function ($scope, $log) {
  $scope.title = "Some Title";
}]);

app.controller("ChildController", ['$scope', '$log', function ($scope, $log){
  $scope.$watch('$parent.title', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    $log.info('title was %s', oldValue);
    $log.info('title is now %s', newValue);
  });
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks! `$scope.$watch('$parent.vm.title' ..` did the trick. Could you please tell me what would be a more standardized way of structuring the controller JS?

Comment: Sure, the way I structured it above is what AngularJS has as structured controllers. Take a look at their documentation for controllers to get the full info on it https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller

Comment: Thanks helped me either. but the $watch is hitting twice. how can we over come with this.

Answer (score 0):

Parent Controller :

```
$scope.cancelFlag = false;
```

Child Controller  :

1) `$parent.cancelFlag` refers the parent controller.

2) If we make any changes in parent controller, watch will be invoked in child controller.

Example :

```
$scope.cancelFlag = true or false;
```

3) Here we can call child controller method by making changes in parent    controller.

```
     $scope.$watch('$parent.cancelFlag', 
     function (newVal, oldVal)
     {
        if (newVal != null && newVal==true)
            $scope.childControllerMethod();
    });
    $scope.childControllerMethod= function () { };
```